# get key from localhost reverse send it back not working

Tags: python-3.x, server, port, send

I have made a request for a key from 'localhost', 10000. I then reversed the received key. I now need to send the key back. I thought this code:

> sock.send(r_data)
> print(r_data)
> sock.close()

would send the reversed key back but it is not. Any help is welcome!

```
import socket
import sys

ip = 'localhost'
port = 10000
addr = (ip, port)

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(addr)

key = sock.send(b"GET_KEY")
data = sock.recv(1024)

r_data = data[::-1]

sock.send(r_data)
print(r_data)
sock.close()
```